# How do I make responsive uneven columns on Boostrap using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

[I want to make this using HTML and CSS:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IXp7.png)

[image]

I understand how the bootstrap grid works, however I'm having trouble creating columns that are longer than the rest, without adding additional space between the other rows. (When I add padding to the center column, the first box on the second row lowers). I will be putting links in each box.

Thanks!

Edit 1: I'm using Yii 2 Framework.
Edit 2: Added current HTML

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2" >1,2,3</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1">content</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1">content</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2"> 1,2,3</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4">1,2,3</div>
  
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2">content</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4">content</div>
  
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-offset-8 col-sm-offset-8 col-md-offset-8 col-lg-offset-8">content</div>
  
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-offset-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2">content</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Is each row wrapped with a "row" class?  This will ensure that the items clear their floats correctly.

Comment: Yes it is! 
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2 bstest"> HEY</div>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

Sadly that's not how Bootstrap works; you get a single row that you can place columns within and you can't float another column underneath others and have it all automatically adjust like your diagram.

I would suggest checking out the jQuery plugin called [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/) which does help with layouts like you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll check it out! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why this couldn't work. The trick is that it has to be done in two rows.

The first row should contain 3 columns. In each of those 3 columns, you can create any number of rows that you need.

The second row contains only 1 full-width column.

Please see the code sample below for a better explanation:

```
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="height:200px;">
            <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 100%;">
                <div class="row" style="height:100%;">
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="height:25%">12 Columns</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" style="height:25%">4 Columns</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" style="height:25%">4 Columns</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" style="height:25%">4 Columns</div>
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="height:50%">12 Columns</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 100%;">
                <div class="row" style="height:100%;">
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="height:100%">12 Columns</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                </div>                      
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 100%;">
                <div class="row" style="height:100%;">
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="height:25%">12 Columns</div>
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="height:25%">12 Columns</div>
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="height:25%">12 Columns</div>
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="height:25%">12 Columns</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="height:50px;">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="height:100%">12 Columns</div>             
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If all of the content is fixed size, you could definitely nest rows like this.  I guess it depends on whether the OP has a lot of dynamic content and knows all the boxes before hand.

Comment: @Josh thanks so much for your help! I inputted your code in my editor and I see how it would create the layout that I wanted. However, after adding the other classes to the code to make it responsive, like sm and lg, it doesn't behave as expected. Could you explain the nesting a little more?

Answer (score 0):

[Bootstrap4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) might help with [flexbox](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/) inbricated.

Not too sure this is the best example, it still does require some extra CSS to have it run properly:

```css
.container>.d-flex>.col {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px turquoise;
  min-height: 1.5rem;
  height: auto!important;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}

.w-100,
.flex-row.d-flex.col>.border {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px turquoise;
}

.w-100 {
  margin: -10px 10px 20px
}

.container>.col {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.d-flex.flex-column.col>div {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.d-flex.flex-column.col>div.big {/* big or whatever classname you think meaningfull */
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.col .col:hover {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container d-flex flex-wrap flex-row">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column col ">
    <div class="d-flex  col rounded">
      AAAA
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row d-flex  col rounded">
      <div class="col">1</div>
      <div class="col border">2</div>
      <div class="col">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex  col rounded">
      CCCC
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex  col rounded">
      DDDD
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column col">
    <div class="d-flex  flex-column col rounded">
      <h1>hover me </h1><br/>EEEE<br/>EEEE<br/>EEEE<br/>EEEE<br/>EEEE<br/>EEEE<br/>EEEE<br/>EEEE<br/>EEEE<br/>EEEE<br/>EEEE<br/>EEEE<br/>EEEE<br/>EEEE
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column col">
    <div class="d-flex  col rounded">
      <p>FF<br/>FF</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row d-flex  col rounded">
      <div class="col">1</div>
      <div class="col border">2</div>
      <div class="col">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex  col big  rounded">
      HHHH
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-100 rounded"> IIII</div>
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/LjNroE

---

**Another** example from a **boostrap3** structure and **`flex` rules added in the CSS**

```css
.flex, .flexcol {
  display:flex;/* rule around which the flex layout is build, remove it to fall back to regular bootstrap */
}

.row {
  padding:0  20px ;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
}
.flexcol {
  padding:0;
}
.colchild , .footer{
  border:solid gray;
  color:white;
  margin:10px;
  background:linear-gradient(20deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.4), rgba(255,255,255,0.4)) tomato;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px, 0 0 0 3px orange , 0 0 0 6px turquoise;
}

.flexcol {
  flex-direction:column;
}
.col {
  flex:1;
  padding:1em;
}
.colchild.flex .col:nth-child(2) {
  border-left:solid gray;
  border-right:solid gray;
}
.rounded {
  border-radius:0.5em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row container flex">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4   flexcol ">
    <div class="colchild rounded">
      <p>boxe</p>
    </div>
    <div class="colchild rounded flex">
      <div class="col"> 1 </div>
      <div class="col"> 2 </div>
      <div class="col"> 3 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="colchild rounded">
      <p>boxe</p>
    </div>
    <div class="colchild rounded">
      <p>boxe</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4   flexcol ">
    <div class="colchild rounded col">
      <p>boxe</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4    flexcol ">
    <div class="colchild rounded">
      <p>boxe</p>
    </div>
    <div class="colchild rounded flex">
      <div class="col"> 1 </div>
      <div class="col"> 2 </div>
      <div class="col"> 3 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="colchild rounded col ">
      <p>bottom</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="row container flex">
  <div class="footer w-100 col rounded">footer</div>
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VzKvKv/

Comment: Thanks so much! However, I'm using the Yii 2 Framework which only supports bootstrap 3, would there be a way to override that and use the flexbox?

Comment: @MyName , yes of course, it needs to be fully written in the css file , if you'd set  a snippet in your question providing your HTML and boostrap classes , there would be a way to show you how to overwrite the class to use the flex model..

Comment: I just edited the original question post and added the HTML, hope I added what you were looking for, thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @MyName okay i see, unfortunately, you have rows with different amont of boxes. This structure will not allow boxes to span across different parents. If you noticed my example, boxes are spread into 3 boxes side by sides. Such a structure would work : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VzKvKv ... not too sure about the bootstrap3 rules picked up to set the unflex layout . remove first rule to see behavior difference.

Comment: @MyName , BTW,  to draw a column layout, best is to go from column ;)